# Extjs SlideOut panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to slide out a panel and then hide it using extjs. The slideout is working fine but as soon as I add the hide function it stops working. How do I fix this.
My function is as below.

```
toggleSidebar : function () {
    var sidebar = this.getSidebar();
    if(sidebar.hidden){
        sidebar['show'](); 
    }else{
        sidebar.el.slideOut('l', {
            easing: 'easeOut',
            duration: 200,
            scope: this,
            callback: this.onSidebarAnim()
        });
        sidebar['hide'](); // Slide works if I remove this line. 
    }


},
```

Comment: what does the console say? any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation is an asynchronous process, and `slideOut` does not block until animation has finished; in fact your code starts to animate the panel and then hides it immediately. That is why it's not working the way you expect it to.

The solution is to hide the panel *after* the animation has finished. That is what callback is for, except that in your original code instead of passing the function in `callback` property, you're calling it and assigning the result of its execution to the `callback` property. That is not going to work, and in fact it's going to blow up with "foo not a function" exception.

```
toggleSidebar: function () {
    var sidebar = this.getSidebar();

    if (sidebar.hidden) {
        sidebar.show(); 
    }
    else {
        sidebar.el.slideOut('l', {
            easing: 'easeOut',
            duration: 200,
            scope: this,
            // Pass the function itself, note no parentheses:
            callback: this.onSidebarAnim
        });
    }
},

onSidebarAnim: function() {
    this.getSidebar().hide();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex removing the parenthese helped. It did not give me any exception with the parenthese too. Do you know how will I handle slideIn after this ? Basically I am trying to build 2 panel application with left side sliding in and out. If I hide it the slideIn wont work until I show it again.

Comment: @Asharan Could you use border layout instead? Take a look at the KitchenSink example.